# Capture PayPal Order

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When integrating with PayPal's V2 Orders API [using the NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK/pull/46/files), when is the correct time to fulfil the order (e.g. ship a product to the customer).

```
async function captureOrder(orderId) {
    try {
        const request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(orderId);
        request.requestBody({});
        const response = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
        // Is it safe to assume, if the above line didn't reject, the order has been successfully captured?...or do we need to verify the status of the order / capture etc.
        return response;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a positive check before shipment, you could check for a `status` of `COMPLETED`, which is the value documented in the API reference for success https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

A recoverable funding failure issue of `INSTRUMENT_DECLINED`, and any non-recoverable situations, should be dealt with according to the logic in https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I guess my question is, do I need to perform a positive check for the `status` of `COMPLETED` -- i.e. if "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED" (or any other failure) occurred during capture, should I expect that the execute call to reject?

Comment: Additionally, and the reason I'm asking this question, is because we have a PayPal Order in production with status 'COMPLETED' but the capture status is 'DECLINED', so I'm trying to figure out how / why it got into this state.

Comment: Which seems incorrect given the PayPal docs say this about the order.status -- "COMPLETED: The payment was authorized or the authorized payment was captured for the order."

Comment: There are two statuses, the top level order status, and the purchase_units[0].captures.status which you can see in the sample response on the right.  You'll want to check the latter, and that capture ID is the PayPal transaction ID for accounting purposes.

Comment: So even if an order is "COMPLETED", i,e, "The payment was authorized or the authorized payment was captured for the order.", it doesn't necessarily mean the payment was captured?

Comment: Right, the obvious case being if it was an order with intent:authorize

Comment: Yes, so assuming it's an order with `intent: CAPTURE`, the docs then can be interpreted as saying "COMPLETED" === "The payment was captured for the order.", is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes. And that capture itself can, in turn, have a number of statuses that are independent of the completed order status https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#definition-capture_status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222305/discussion-between-riscarrott-and-preston-phx).